# FTP application written in Perl doesn't connect

Tags: perl, ftp, timeout

Why doesn't my program work? It refuses to connect to the host, I've tried two different servers and verified which port is used.
Note that I'm not very experienced when it comes to Perl.

```
use strict;
use Net::FTP;
use warnings;

my $num_args = $#ARGV+1;
my $filename;
my $port;
my $host;
my $ftp;



if($num_args < 2)
{
    print "Usage: ftp.pl host [port] file\n";
    exit();
}
elsif($num_args == 3)
{
    $port = $ARGV[1];
    $host = $ARGV[0];
    $filename = $ARGV[2];
    print "Connecting to $host on port $port.\n";
    $ftp = Net::FTP->new($host, Port => $port, Timeout => 30, Debug => 1)
       or die "Can't open $host on port $port.\n";
}
else
{
    $host = $ARGV[0];
    $filename = $ARGV[1];
    print "Connecting to $host with the default port.\n";
    $ftp = Net::FTP->new($host, Timeout => 30, Debug => 1)
       or die "Can't open $host on port $port.\n";
}

print "Usename: ";
my $username = <>;
print "\nPassword: ";
my $password = <>;

$ftp->login($username, $password);
$ftp->put($filename) or die "Can't upload $filename.\n";

print "Done!\n";

$ftp->quit;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you should elaborate on the "does not work" part. Error messages, etc. How do you know it does not connect?

Comment: There are no error messages. An elaboration shouldn't be necessary, it does not connect. That is, Net::FTP->new() fails. That's it.

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Net::FTP can't have failed, or the script would have died. Do you get to the user/password prompt? And have you remembered to `chomp` username and password?

Comment: Your code works for me, but you want to use `<STDIN>` when prompting for input.

Comment: @TLP The script did die, which is how I know it couldn't connect. As I said, my experience with Perl is very low. I thought that New::FTP was the actual connection, was my assumption wrong?
And no, I haven't used chomp. I had no idea that was necessary.
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Ben
Oh, so my code worked? I thought <> was an abbreviation for <STDIN>, aren't they the same?
Hmm, I wonder why it doesn't work for me. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: If it died, then you do have an error message. That's an important piece of information when diagnosing your problem. You will have an error in `$@`.

Comment: @Griffin `<>` will work differently depending on whether or not you have command line arguments. See [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators)

Comment: @TLP Sorry, I thought you were referring to errors during compilation.
I don't know the meaning of $@.
In any case, the code seems to work for Ben.

Comment: @Griffin `<>` will be confusing for the script, but since it died before then, the error lies elsewhere. Which is why it is pretty vital to know that it **died** at the connect. Read the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::FTP).

Comment: @TLP Alright, sorry. I thought I was obvious, sorry if I was ambiguous. Since Ben ran the code without any problems, is it safe to assume there isn't anything wrong with the code? Rather there's a problem with either the two FTP servers I tried or some of my configurations (which seems unlikely since I've used other FTP clients).
Could permissions or the like cause problems like this?
Thanks.
Edit: I run Arch Linux.

Comment: @Griffin I repeat: You will have an error message in `$@`. In the documentation cited above, it will show you how to use it in your die statement to get the error. The error will hopefully give you more information.

Comment: @TLP, ah! It works after I included the $@ and changed <> to <STDIN>. Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you already have your answer `<>` -> `<STDIN>`, I think I see the problem. When `@ARGV` contains anything, `<>` is the 'magic open'. Perl interprets the next item in `@ARGV` as a filename, opens it and reads it line by line. Therefore, I think you can probably do something like:

```
use strict;
use Net::FTP;
use warnings;

use Scalar::Util 'looks_like_number';

if(@ARGV < 2)
{
    print "Usage: ftp.pl host [port] file [credentials file]\n";
    exit();
}

my $host = shift; # or equiv shift @ARGV;
my $port = (looks_like_number $ARGV[0]) ? shift : 0;
my $filename = shift;

my @ftp_args = (
  $host,
  Timeout => 30,
  Debug => 1
);

if ($port)
}
    print "Connecting to $host on port $port.\n";
    push @ftp_args, (Port => $port);
}
else
{
    print "Connecting to $host with the default port.\n";
}
my $ftp = Net::FTP->new(@ftp_args)
     or die "Can't open $host on port $port.\n";

#now if @ARGV is empty reads STDIN, if not opens file named in current $ARGV[0] 

print "Usename: ";
chomp(my $username = <>); #reads line 1 of file
print "\nPassword: ";
chomp(my $password = <>); #reads line 2 of file

$ftp->login($username, $password);
$ftp->put($filename) or die "Can't upload $filename.\n";

print "Done!\n";

$ftp->quit;
```

Then if you had some connection creditials in a file (say named cred) like

```
myname
mypass
```

then

```
$ ftp.pl host 8020 file cred
```

would open host:8020 for file using credentials in cred.

I'm not sure you want to do that, its just that THAT is how `<>` works.